# AudioKit NodeRecorder not capturing audio: File read returned zero frames

Tags: swift, audiokit

I'm trying to implement a simple recording feature using AudioKit's [NodeRecorder](https://www.audiokit.io/AudioKit/documentation/audiokit/noderecorder). The idea is that a user taps a button to record, taps again to stop recording, and taps yet again to sample their new recording.

I've looked into the [AudioKit Cookbook Recipe](https://github.com/AudioKit/Cookbook/blob/main/Cookbook/CookbookCommon/Sources/CookbookCommon/Recipes/MiniApps/Recorder.swift) for this class, which uses AudioPlayer, whereas my code uses AppleSampler.

When I try and run the start/stop methods, though, my print statement shows that the length of the audioFile is 0, and that the `"File read returned zero frames"`. Printing `recorder.isRecording`  during the record operation shows the variable is being set properly.

Did I set the input and output correctly for the AudioEngine? Thank you!

```
import UIKit
import AudioKit
import AVFoundation

class MIDIButton: UIButton {
    let engine = AudioEngine()
    var sampler = AppleSampler()
    var recorder: NodeRecorder?
    var audioFile: AVAudioFile?
    
    init() {
        guard let input = engine.input else {
            fatalError()
        }

        do {
            recorder = try NodeRecorder(node: input)
        } catch let err {
            fatalError("\(err)")
        }
        
        engine.output = sampler
        setup() //Starts the audioEngine
    }
    
    func startRecording() {
        do {
            try recorder?.record()
        } catch let err {
            print(err)
        }
    }
    
    func stopRecording() {
        recorder?.stop()
        
        if let file = recorder?.audioFile {
            //This is returning 0
            print("audiofile has length \(file.length)")

            handleNewRecording(file) //Handles the recording file
        }
    }
}
```